# Dynamically mount an engine in the router

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I update the router dynamically based on the state in a service during the initializing of the router? Let's say I have 4 engines out of which one must be mounted in an app based on the state in a service and whatever the state may be, the engine mounted must have a specific name irrespective of the fact whatever engine may be mounted.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported at this time, and would likely fall under this issue in the ember-engines repo: https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-engines/issues/99

---

A temporary workaround supposedly exists as of v0.5 of ember-engines (requires ember 2.12 and ember-cli 2.12). You have to create a helper, like `load-engine`, via `ember g helper load-engine`.

Its contents would be:

```
export default Ember.Helper.extend({
  assetLoader: Ember.inject.service(),

  compute([name]) {
    if (this.engineName === name && this._resolved) { return name; }

    this.engineName = name;

    let assetLoader = this.get('assetLoader');
    assetLoader.loadBundle(name)
      .then(() => {
        this._resolved = true;
        this.recompute();
      });

    return null;
  }
});
```

Then you'd use it like so:

```
{{mount (load-engine boundEngineName)}}
```

Note: Originally posted by https://github.com/mike183 in the Ember slack channel